# I am downloading multiple files using electron-dl but progressbar is getting corrupted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

I am developing an application using React and electron. I need to download 2 files. I am downloading two files with .exe and .svg extensions. However, because the .svg file is small in size, the download ends immediately. In fact, while there is a file with a total size of 5 megabytes, since the svg is 128kb, the progressbar reaches 100% when downloading the svg file. However, even though there are still 4.5 megabytes of undownloaded files, the download acts as if it's completely finished.

**main.ts**

```
ipcMain.on('download', (event, info) => {
info.properties.onTotalProgress = (status) =>
  mainWindow.webContents.send('download progress', status);
download(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), info.url, info.properties)
.then((dl) => mainWindow.webContents.send('download complete', dl.getSavePath())
).catch(console.error);
```

**App.tsx**

```
 /*Download*/
 const downloadPath = path.resolve('/', './exes');
  const downloadPathWindows = `${downloadPath}\\${index}`;
  ipcRenderer.send('download', {
    url: `https://adv.com${book.SmartBookUrl}`,
    properties: {
      directory: downloadPathWindows,
    },
  });
  ipcRenderer.send('download', {
    url: `https://adv.com${book.CoverImageUrl}`,
    properties: {
      directory: downloadPathWindows,
    },
  });


  /*Progress Bar*/
  ipcRenderer.on('download progress', (event, progress) => {
     const progressInPercentages = Math.floor(progress.percent * 100);
     setprogressNumber(progressInPercentages);
  });


  /*Download Complate*/
  ipcRenderer.on('download complete', (event) => {
     setprogressNumber(0);
  };
```

Comment: Well, what's "broken", exactly? What is your `download()` function of the main process doing? What do you exactly mean by "the download acts as if the download is finished before the other large file"? All of this is not particularly specific, but the more specific your question is, the easier and faster we can help you. Please [edit] your question and give use more context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've updated the question. The whole problem is while there are files with a total size of 5mb. While my svg 128kb .exe file is 4.9mb in size. As soon as I download the svg file, the progress bar goes to 100% and says download finished. @AlexanderLeithner

Comment: For me the issue was caused by redefining to every call at the ipcRender 'download' the 2 ipcRenderer : "download progress" & "download complete" too. By separating these 2 ipcRenderer  to the ipcRenderer 'download', it is works like a charm.